# Wie nennt man eine Wortveredelung durch Komposition?

Tags: style, compound, neologism

Immer wieder begegnet man vor allem in der Werbung und bei Produktbezeichnungen einer eigenartigen Wortneuschöpfung durch Bildung von zusammengesetzten Wörtern wie:

> - **Edelschokolade**
> - **Landmilch**
> - **Komfortkissen**

Es ist aber nun nicht so, dass diese Kompositionen eine andersartige Eigenschaft beschrieben (so wie *Speiseöl* sich von *Motoröl* unterscheidet). Im Gegenteil, die *"Edelschokolade"* ist natürlich eine ganz gewöhnliche Schokolade, die *"Landmilch"* wird von Kühen - wem sonst? - gewonnen und das "*Komfortkissen"* dient wie jedes Kissen dem Komfort.

Vielmehr soll dadurch offenbar einem Produkt ein für die Vermarktung besseres Image  verliehen werden. Schier inflationär wird dies auch mit weiteren Präfixen erreicht, die sich in allen erdenklichen Wortkombinationen finden lassen. Hier nur einige Beispiele:

> **Profi-, Luxus-, Designer-, Aktiv-, Bio-, ...**

Wird dieses Stilmittel nur im Marketing eingesetzt und gibt es einen speziellen Fachausdruck dafür?

Comment: Die Profiluxusdesignerbohrmaschine jetzt suuuuper günstig. Kaufen Sie jetzt, sonst sparen Sie nie!

Comment: ... und Sie bekommen einen Nagel gratis! ;)

Comment: Wobei "Bio", wenn es richtig benutzt wird, Herkunft und/oder Verarbeitung genauer definiert.

Comment: @Feroc: Eben, eine Naturprofiluxusdesignerbohrmaschine also bitte! Schön auch: Königspilsener u. Königsnüsse.

Comment: Auch Worte wie _messerscharf_ und _blitzschnell_ sind Veredelungen oder Steigerungen durch Komposition, ob sie dem Marketing entspringen weiß ich nicht.

Comment: _Edelschokolade_ kann durchaus eine andersartige Eigenschaft verglichen mit "normaler" Schokolade haben, wenn Sie aus _Edelkakao_ statt _Konsumkakao_ hergestellt wird, der Begriff _Edelschokolade_ ist allerdings nicht geschützt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ein Wort könnte als **[Tautologie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautologie_%28Sprache%29)** ...

> Der Ausdruck Tautologie (von altgriechisch ταὐτό = τὸ αὐτό to autó ‚dasselbe‘ sowie λόγος lógos ‚Sprechen, Rede‘) bezeichnet in der Stilistik und Rhetorik eine rhetorische Figur, bei der mit einer inhaltlichen Wiederholung (semantischen Redundanz) gearbeitet wird. Ein Gegenbegriff zu Tautologie ist das Oxymoron. Bewusste Tautologien werden in so genannten ‚Zwillingsformeln‘ geprägt.

... oder **[Pleonasmus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmus)** bezeichnet werden:

> Ein Pleonasmus (griech. πλεονασμóς pleonasmós „Überfluss“) ist eine rhetorische Erscheinung, bei der innerhalb einer Wortgruppe eine bestimmte Bedeutung mehrfach auf unterschiedliche Weise (oft mit verschiedenen Wortarten, etwa Adjektiv/Substantiv) zum Ausdruck gebracht wird oder bei der Ausdrucksmittel verwendet werden, die keine zusätzliche Information beisteuern (verbale Redundanz). Geschieht dies bewusst, kann es sich um eine epithetische rhetorische Figur handeln: Der Pleonasmus wird dann zur Verstärkung, Verdeutlichung oder besonderen Hervorhebung des Gesagten verwendet („kaltes Eis“; „mit meinen eigenen Händen angefasst“).

Der Unterschied zwischen Tautologie und Pleonasmus erklärt Wikipedia auch:

> „Tautologie“ und „Pleonasmus“ werden weiterhin auch wertend unterschieden, was wiederum eine Frage terminologischen Beliebens ist, ohne dass sich ein fester Sprachgebrauch ausmachen lässt. Die Tautologie soll dann eine „Verdopplung zum Zwecke der rhetorischen Verstärkung“ sein, der Pleonasmus hingegen eine „überflüssige Häufung, die z. T. als abweichend empfunden wird“.

Es gibt jedoch verschiedene Traditionen der Unterscheidung von Tautologie und Pleonasmus, die in den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikeln eingehender beschrieben werden.

In den beiden Wikipedia-Artikeln finden sich zahlreiche Beispiele, die *nicht der Marketingsprache* entstammen, z.B.:

> Glasvitrine
>   Pulsschlag
>   Düsenjet
>   Haarfrisur
>   Einzelinduviduum
>   nasser Regen
>   alter Greis
>   runde Kugel
>   PIN-Nummer
>   ABM-Maßnahme

Die von Dir genannten Wörter würde ich entsprechend als **pleonastische Komposita** oder **tautologische Komposita** bezeichnen, wobei die Pleonasmen/Tautologien im Falle von *Komfortkissen* oder *Landmilch* zur Steigerung eingesetzt werden oder im Falle von *Edelschokolade* eine andersartige Eigenschaft suggerieren sollen (vgl. Edelkakao und Konsumkakao).

Wenn ich mit der Bezeichnung auf die verwendeten Wortarten abzielen möchte, würde ich Deine Beispiele *Komfortkissen* und *Landmilch* eher als **tautologische Komposita** und *Edelschokolade* als **pleonastisches Kompositum** bezeichnen.

Answer (score 1):

Das Mittel wird nicht nur zur Steigerung des Ansehens einer Sache verwandt, sondern ebenso zur Minderung:

```
    Discountschokolade
    Industriemilch
    Kratzkissen
```

Es ist einfach die Freiheit der Sprache, die die Bildung von Verbindungen erlaubt, und jeder ist frei diese zu eigenem Zweck und Ausdruck zu verwenden. Die Werbung würde demnach mit dem gleichen Wasser kochen wie alle anderen auch.

Was hier als Veredelung daherkommt, kann dort als Spott erscheinen; was hier aufwertend gemeint ist, wirkt dort abwertend:

```
    Komfortguillotine 
    Landsparkassendirektor 
    Berufsdemonstrant
```

Des Weiteren gibt es natürlich ganz profane Konstruktionen, um Dinge verächtlich zu machen:

```
    Schrottimmobilie 
    Drecksarbeit
    Schandfrieden
```

Und dann gibt es freilich einfach beschreibende Bezeichnungen, die je nachdem, wozu man sie in Kontrast setzt, als Qualität oder als Mangel einer solchen erscheinen können: Ein Schwarzwaldschinken ist kein Serranoschinken, aber doch immerhin – der Moselriesling, das 4-Sterne-Hotel, der Bezirksbürgermeister.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist fest davon auszugehen, dass dies den Köpfen der Marketingleute entspringt. Dies legt zumindest eine Magisterarbeit mit dem Titel [Die Neubildungen von Wörtern und Phrasen in der Werbung](http://www.diplom.de/ean/9783836643603) und deren Extrakt bei Google nahe:

> Komponente stellen oft **Zusatzwörter** dar, die das Wort umschreiben
>   sollen. (vgl. Grosse ..... 2 Empirische Ergebnisse sprechen dafür,
>   dass der „Große“ (=Marktführer) vom „Kleinen“ mehr **profi**- ..... Pooler
>   **Luxus** (‚Purer **Luxus**') ...... Tiger **Design** ...